# window.pageYOffset returns inaccurate value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to be able to detect when the boundaries of an element are in the viewport - easy enough. To do this I'm using jQuery's `scroll` event. After setting up a basic test, I noticed that the value that `window.scrollY` and `window.pageYOffset` returns is inaccurate.

[image]

The height of each `div` is 1000px, but my `window.scrollY` and `window.pageYOffset` returns 756 ?

Any ideas? Is there something that I'm missing?

(This seems to be the case in the newest version of Chrome & Firefox)

Comment: Why do you say `window.pageYOffset` is inaccurate?  I don't see anything that suggests that.

Comment: The height of the `div` is 1000px, the value being returned is 756px, unless I'm missing something that's not correct.

Comment: Please post a fiddle or other example so we can see your complete code.

Comment: It's pretty straight forward, I don't think a fiddle would help.. there's just a couple of lines of JS. ` ($ window).on 'scroll', (e) ->    
        console.log ($ this).scrollTop(), window.pageYOffset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need to support IE7 or something, you shouldn't be using those elements to determine if something is in the viewport or not. Something like this is far superior:

```
function isInWindow(el){
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
        $window = $(window);

    return (
        (rect.top >= 0) && 
        (rect.left >= 0) && 
        (rect.right <= $window.width()) && 
        (rect.bottom <= $window.height())
    );
}

isInWindow($element.get(0));

// or for multiple

$element.each(function(){
    isInWindow(this);
});
```

I know you're probably still curious about why the values are different, but this should get you to your goal of whether in browser window or not.

Comment: I'll definitely try this. Thanks.

Comment: Even though this didn't answer my question, it did help point me in a better direction. Thank you.